# Multidimensional array of Objects in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, oop, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin, and I want to create a multi dimensional array of a custom class, with `null` permitted. Something like that

```
private var array_map = arrayOf<Array<Obstacle?>>()

...

array_map[1][2] = Obstacle()
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `private var arrayMap: Array<Array<Obstacle?>> = arrayOf()`. Just wrap with as much `Array<>` as you need.

Answer (score 13):

In case you need the index of each element in the constructor of the elements of the array:

Declaration:

```
var matrix: Array<Array<Obstacle?>>
```

Instantiation and initialization:

```
matrix = Array(numRows) { row ->
            Array(numCols) { col ->
                Obstacle(row, col)
            }
         }
```

Comment: honestly, this clarifies so much that this snippet should go directly to kotlinlang.org/docs ))

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but imagine that `Obstacle` is a custom class with a field `num` as below

```
data class Obstacle(var num: Int){}
```

A 2D array of the `Obstacle` object would be as below:

```
val array: Array<Obstacle?> = arrayOf(Obstacle(123), Obstacle(234))
val arrayOfArray: Array<Array<Obstacle?>> = arrayOf(array)
println(arrayOfArray[0][0]) // would print Obstacle(num=123)
println(arrayOfArray[0][1]) // would print Obstacle(num=234)
```

So you should be declaring your 2D array as below

```
val arrayOfArray: Array<Array<Obstacle?>> = arrayOf()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will compile as is. The problem is just that array size can't be changed and `arrayOf<Array<Obstacle?>>()` creates an empty array, so `array_map[1][2] = Obstacle()` fails at runtime. (Unless you do `array_map = ...` somewhere between them. Note that you should prefer `val arrayMap`, which can't be reassigned, unless you have a specific reason to use `var`.)

If you want your array to start with nulls, there is [`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) in the standard library, but it only creates a single-dimensional array, and what you really need is an array of arrays of nulls. You can write a helper function:

```
inline fun <reified T> matrixOfNulls(n: Int, m: Int) = Array(n) { arrayOfNulls<T>(m) }

private val arrayMap = matrixOfNulls<Obstacle>(5, 5) // example arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I always use for this case is:

```
arr2D = Array(sizeA) { Array(sizeB) { content } }
```

Note I replaced the sizes by fields names to illustrate that each number/field represents the width and height length of each dimension of the 2D array.

Also, `content` should be replaced by the main content you want to fill in each coordinate, in your case seems you aims to setup with `Obstacle()` instances. If you want fill this content in other moment put `null` or a quick `Any()` reference.

In this last case, after creating that you can simply perform to set the itens:

```
arr2D[1][2] = Obstacle()
```